# Adding Google Search Bar to Android App

Tags: android, search, listview

I'd like to to add a Google search bar to my app.  Then I would like only the title of the search results to show up in a list view.  What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just contact the google api for searching and parse the json or xml results, extracting exactly what information you want.

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html